# how to setting the field using Session Variables in $set to Update a Single MongoDB Document in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm beginner in php and this is my first time posting a comment.

In MongoDB how do you use ***Session variable in $set*** to update a value?

For example, consider a collection school with the following document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fb5a71fc930cc7b988b20ca"
    },
    "SchoolsState": "JOHOR",
    "SchoolsName": "KOLEJ TINGKATAN ENAM PONTIAN",
    "SchoolsCity": "PONTIAN",
    "SchoolsPhoneNo": "11",

}
```

I want to do something like the below to update where the `SchoolsName == $_SESSION["loggeduser_schoolName"]`, then change the SchoolsPhoneNo:

```
if (isset($_POST['EditSchoolFormSubmit'])) 
{
  $varSchoolsPhoneNo= $_POST['txtSchoolsPhoneNo'];
  $schoolname = $_SESSION["loggeduser_schoolName"];

  $GoNGetzSmartSchoolFrontEndConnectionString="mongodb://admin:******";
  $GoNGetzSmartSchoolFrontEnd= new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($GoNGetzSmartSchoolFrontEndConnectionString);
  $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);
  $bulk->update(['SchoolsName'=> $schoolname],
                ['$set' => ['SchoolsPhoneNo'=>$varSchoolsPhoneNo]],
                ['upsert' => true]
               );
.
.
.
```

I have tried using this command

```
  $bulk->update(['SchoolsName'=>'KOLEJ TINGKATAN ENAM PONTIAN'],
                ['$set' => ['SchoolsPhoneNo'=>$varSchoolsPhoneNo]],
                ['upsert' => true]
               );
```

it worked very well, but if I use session.. there is no change at all.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION["loggeduser_schoolName"]);` to make sure you have the right value saved in your session.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution .Just need to **add strval**.

```
$schoolname = strval($_SESSION["loggeduser_schoolName"]);
```